# Simple past or present perfect? (in unknown point in time in the past)

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

Describing the typical Twitter user:

> I criticize what you wrote/have written and then I block you, without
>   waiting for your reply.

Which one is correct? Thank you.

Comment: If you see the chart in the top answer on the linked question, *I ate* is the equivalent of *you wrote* and refers to a point; *I have eaten* is equivalent of *you have written* and covers a time range.

Comment: @andrew-leach Can this very specific question, about a specific sentence and a specific situation, really be 'an exact duplicate' of a question which is a very general discussion about the English tense system?  Now, you can say the present question is off-topic, better suited to ELL, etc. But an 'exact duplicate' of that linked question?

Comment: That particular banner is set in the system, and is not the most helpful. It simply means that the question is answered elsewhere (see the message at the top, along with my comment). While this question may be specific, the principles it asks about are general.